# Merge battery and batteries tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there is a [battery](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) tag with 1 QA, and a [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) tag with many more.

May I recommend merging the two tags, and creating a synonym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! Yes, this is clearly a case where it makes sense to create a synonym. I've completed both suggested actions:

- Added [battery](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) as a synonym of [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries).
- Merged the tags so that [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/how-much-of-the-car-batteries-are-reused) is now tagged properly.

Comment: You're welcome.  And thank *you*!